# Counting unique combinations up until a date - per month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking into a table with transaction data of a two-sided platform, where you have buyers and sellers. I want to know the total amount of unique combinations of buyers and sellers. Let's say, Abe buys from Brandon in January, that's 1 combination. If Abe buys with Cece in February, that makes 2, but if Abe then buys from Brandon again, it's still 2.

My solution was to use the DENSE_RANK() function:

```
WITH
combos AS (
  SELECT
        t.buyerid, t.sellerid,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.buyerid, t.sellerid) AS combinations

    FROM transactions t

    WHERE t.transaction_date < '2018-05-01'
)
SELECT
    MAX(combinations) AS total_combinations

FROM combos
```

This works fine. Each new combo gets a higher rank, and if you select the MAX of that result, you know the amount of unique combos.

However, I want to know this total amount of unique combos on a per month basis. The problem here is that if I group per transaction month, it only counts the unique combos in that month. In the example of Abe, it would be a unique combo in January, and then another combo in the next month, because that's how grouping works in SQL.

Example:

```
transaction_date  buyerid  sellerid
2018-01-03        3828     219
2018-01-08        2831     123
2018-02-10        3828     219
```

The output of DENSE_RANK() named combinations over all these rows is:

```
transaction_date  buyerid  sellerid  combinations
2018-01-03        3828     219       1
2018-01-08        2831     123       2
2018-02-10        3828     219       2
```

And therefore, when selecting the MAX combinations you know the amount of unique buyer/seller combos, which is here.

However, I would like to see a running total of unique combos up until each start of the month, for all months until now. But, when we group on month, it would go like this:

```
transaction_date  buyerid  sellerid  month combinations
2018-01-03        3828     219       jan   1
2018-01-08        2831     123       jan   2
2018-02-10        3828     219       feb   1
```

While I actually would want an output like:

```
month  total_combinations_at_month_start
jan    0
feb    2
mar    2
```

How should I solve this? I've tried to find help on all kinds of window functions, but no luck until now. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've added sample and expected results.

Comment: Does Gordon's solution work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: Why isn't the march number = 3 in the final expected result set?

Comment: Because there's only been 2 unique combinations until then - buyer 3828 with seller 219 (twice), and buyer 2831 with seller 123. If you would only look at February, it would be a unique combination in February alone, but for each month I want to look all the way back in time until the beginning of that month.

Comment: Ah ok got it thanks - will work on this for you tomorrow

Comment: Daniel - Gordon has adjusted his answer and this solution works. Thank you for your help nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
WITH combos AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sellerid, buyerid ORDER BY t.transaction_date) as combo_seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sellerid, buyerid, date_trunc('month', t.transaction_date) ORDER BY t.transaction_date) as combo_month_seqnum
      FROM transactions t

      WHERE t.transaction_date < '2018-05-01'
    )
SELECT 'Overall' as which, COUNT(*)
FROM combos
WHERE combo_seqnum = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'), COUNT(*)
FROM combos
WHERE combo_month_seqnum = 1
GROUP BY to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM');
```

This puts the results in separate rows.  If you want a cumulative number and number per month:

```
SELECT to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'),
       SUM( (combo_month_seqnum = 1)::int ) as uniques_in_month,
       SUM(SUM( (combo_seqnum = 1)::int )) OVER (ORDER BY to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')) as uniques_through_month
FROM combos
GROUP BY to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/ABZR73843) is a rextester illustrating the solution.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for pitching in. However, the output of this query gives exactly the number 1 in each row (per month). Also if I replace the ORDER BY t.transaction_date in the first ROW_NUMBER function with ORDER BY t.buyerid, t.sellerid. Because if you only take transaction date, I don't see how it would count the unique combos of buyers and seller?

Comment: Gordon, it worked. Thank you for your help and your swift response.